# Reload data to textbox after jqgrid "reloadGrid" action

Tags: asp.net, json, jqgrid

I use a modal form to update/create my records "reloadGrid" method enables the grid [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lccu.png) to refresh from within the modal "save" bouton, but 
   1) my form below does not get updated. 
   2) the last selected row on the jqGrid table gets not selected.

I tried to manualy force the row to be selected with 
jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setSelection', selRowID, true);
but selected row returns null.
Below is the function that saves the updated record and is suposed to trigger the grid and the controls update:

```html
//function SauvegarderMessage(IDMessage) {
function ModifierDemandeur() {
    //console.log("Modifier");

    var xCodeDdeur = $('#txtCode_Demandeur').val();
    var xAddDdeur = $('#txtAdresse_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDVille = $('#cbxVille_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDProv = $('#cbxProvince_Demandeur').val();
    var xCPDdeur = $('#txtCodePostal_Demandeur').val();
    var xTel1Ddeur = $('#txtTel1_Demandeur').val();
    var xTel2Ddeur = $('#txtTel2_Demandeur').val();
    var xTel3Ddeur = $('#txtTel3_Demandeur').val();
    var xCour1Ddeur = $('#Courriel1_Demandeur').val();
    var xCour2Ddeur = $('#Courriel2_Demandeur').val();
    var xCour3Ddeur = $('#Courriel3_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDSitMat = $('#cbxSitMat_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDSexe = $('#cbxSexe_Demandeur').val();
    var xDteNais = $('#txtDteNaissance').val();
    var xRevDdeur = $('#txtrevenu_demandeur').val();
    var xIDOcc = $('#cbxOccupation_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDScol = $('#cbxScolarite_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDStatLegal = $('#cbxStatutLegal_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDComm = $('#cbxCommunaute_Demandeur').val();
    var xIDSceInfo = $('#cbxSourceInformation_Demandeur').val();
    var xHandicape = $('#cbHandi').val();
    var xRef = $('#txtReference_Demandeur').val();
    var xRemDdeur = $('#Remarques_Demandeur').val();


    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "../Conseiller/UpdateDemandeurs",
        data: {

            Code_Demandeur: xCodeDdeur,
            Adresse_Demandeur: xAddDdeur,
            ID_Ville: xIDVille,
            ID_Province: xIDProv,
            CodePostal_Demandeur: xCPDdeur,
            Tel1_Demandeur: xTel1Ddeur,
            Tel2_Demandeur: xTel2Ddeur,
            Tel3_Demandeur: xTel3Ddeur,
            Courriel1_Demandeur: xCour1Ddeur,
            Courriel2_Demandeur: xCour2Ddeur,
            Courriel3_Demandeur: xCour3Ddeur,
            ID_SituationMatrimoniale: xIDSitMat,
            ID_Sexe: xIDSexe,
            Date_Naissance_Demandeur: xDteNais,
            Revenu_Demandeur: xRevDdeur,
            ID_Occupation: xIDOcc,
            ID_Scolarite: xIDScol,
            ID_StatutLegal: xIDStatLegal,
            ID_Communaute: xIDComm,
            ID_SourceInformation: xIDSceInfo,
            Handicape: xHandicape,
            Reference: xRef,
            Remarques_Demandeur: xRemDdeur,
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            //console.log(data)
            //console.log(data.rows);
            $('#modifierProfilModal').modal('hide');
            if (data != null) {
                jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('clearGridData')
                      .jqGrid('setGridParam', { data: data, datatype: 'json' })
                      .trigger('reloadGrid')
                for (var i = 0; i < data.Data.records; i += 1) {
                    var selRowID = data.Data.rows[i].Code_Demandeur;
                    var selectedRowID = $('#btnModifierProfile').val();
                    if (selRowID == selectedRowID) {
                        //jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setSelection', selRowID, true);                      
                        var selr = jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
                        console.log('Ligne sélectionnée: ' + selr);
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        error: function (err) { console.log(err); }
    });
```

I tried editRow action to force row selection, I tried to set focus to the grid, nothing would do.

Answer (score 0):

A work around would be to identify each field with the last selected element's ID and assign each control appropriate value using document.getElementById('controlID').value = some_json_returned_data; 
But this still not solve the grid row selection issue and does not seem to be a "best practice" way to do.

Answer (score 0):

Coding the "loadComplete" method of qgrid resolved both issue:

```html
        loadComplete: function () {
           if ($('#btnModifierProfile').val() != "")
                jQuery('#grid').jqGrid('setSelection', $('#btnModifierProfile').val());
        },
```

Desired row is selected and related data populated in other controls.